# A question of probability related to rolling of a fair die.

Tags: probability

> > A standard fair die is rolled until some face **other than** $5$ or $6$ turns up. Let $X$ denote the face value of the last roll, and $A = \{X\ \text {is even} \}$ and $B = \{X\ \text {is at most}\ 2 \}.$ Then
> >
> > $(1)$ $P(A \cap B) = 0.$
> >
> > $(2)$ $P(A \cap B) = \frac {1} {6}.$
> >
> > $(3)$ $P(A \cap B) = \frac {1} {4}.$
> >
> > $(4)$ $P(A \cap B) = \frac {1} {3}.$

What I saw is that $X$ can only take the values $1,2,3$ and $4.$ In this case the sample space $S = \{1,2,3,4 \}$ with $A = \{2,4 \}$ and $B = \{1,2 \}.$ So $A \cap B = \{2 \}.$  Hence the required probability is $\frac 1 4.$ So $(3)$ is the correct option according to me. Am I correct? Please check it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: The missing step is to argue not just that $X$ can take only the values $1,2,3,4$, but that it takes each of those values with probability $\frac14$.

Comment: Yeah you are correct @Greg Martin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are correct.
1,2,3,4 - are all "equal" and by symmetry, $P(\{1\}) = P(\{2\}) = P(\{3\}) = P(\{4\})$. Thus, $P(\{2\})=\frac{1}{4},$ and remaining follows by your equations.